# MySQL generating keyring via UDF leads to SQLException

Tags: mysql, database, encryption, plugins

This is a question I also raised in [DBA Stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/209793/mysql-generating-keyring-via-udf-leads-to-sqlexception). I will post here verbatim:

I am trying to encrypt my tables using a keyring plugin that MySQL suggested. In my /etc/my.cnf file, I have set the early-plugin flag as well as the location of the key ring file. It looks something like this:

```
[mysqld]
early-plugin-load=keyring_file.so
keyring_file_data=/usr/local/mysql/mysql-keyring/keyring
```

As root user, I have also installed keyring_udf.so and created some UDFs like so:

```
INSTALL PLUGIN keyring_udf SONAME 'keyring_udf.so';
CREATE FUNCTION keyring_key_generate RETURNS INTEGER SONAME 'keyring_udf.so';
CREATE FUNCTION keyring_key_fetch RETURNS STRING SONAME 'keyring_udf.so';
CREATE FUNCTION keyring_key_length_fetch RETURNS INTEGER SONAME 'keyring_udf.so';
CREATE FUNCTION keyring_key_type_fetch RETURNS STRING SONAME 'keyring_udf.so';
CREATE FUNCTION keyring_key_store RETURNS INTEGER SONAME 'keyring_udf.so';
CREATE FUNCTION keyring_key_remove RETURNS INTEGER SONAME 'keyring_udf.so';
```

From here, I attempt to define a key like so:

```
SELECT keyring_key_generate('MyKey', 'AES', 32);
```

This leads to the following message from the console:

```
[2018-06-15 15:11:38] Streaming result set com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataDynamic@15d7e44 is still active. No statements may be issued when any streaming result sets are open and in use on a given connection. Ensure that you have called .close() on any active streaming result sets before attempting more queries.
[2018-06-15 15:11:38] java.sql.SQLException: Streaming result set com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataDynamic@15d7e44 is still active. No statements may be issued when any streaming result sets are open and in use on a given connection. Ensure that you have called .close() on any active streaming result sets before attempting more queries.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:868)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:864)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkForOutstandingStreamingData(MysqlIO.java:3211)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2443)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2677)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2545)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setSessionMaxRows(ConnectionImpl.java:5432)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1365)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.convertShowWarningsToSQLWarnings(SQLError.java:704)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.convertShowWarningsToSQLWarnings(SQLError.java:656)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.getWarnings(StatementImpl.java:2145)
    at com.intellij.database.remote.jdbc.impl.RemoteStatementImpl.getWarnings(RemoteStatementImpl.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:324)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:276)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:253)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:162)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:227)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:179)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy121.getWarnings(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor360.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.invokeRemote(RemoteUtil.java:169)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.access$300(RemoteUtil.java:36)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil$RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteUtil.java:274)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy122.getWarnings(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.database.console.JdbcEngine.b(JdbcEngine.java:444)
    at com.intellij.database.console.JdbcEngine.a(JdbcEngine.java:397)
    at com.intellij.database.console.JdbcEngine.b(JdbcEngine.java:224)
    at com.intellij.database.console.AbstractEngine.a(AbstractEngine.java:171)
    at com.intellij.database.console.AbstractEngine.a(AbstractEngine.java:148)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

[2018-06-15 15:11:38] [HY000][3188] Function 'keyring_key_generate' failed because underlying keyring service returned an error. Please check if a keyring plugin is installed and that provided arguments are valid for the keyring you are using.
```

I have also tried resetting mysql server: `systemctl restart mysqld`.

The environment is a CentOS server.

After churning for hours trying to get this to work, I have decided to raise the white flag and ask for help from you guys. Thanks for reading/help!

EDIT:

I tried doing the same commands under Windows. Still the same issue with the keyring_udf.dll file. I'm wondering if this is a bug within the plugin? Or is there a crucial MySQL setting I may be missing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and additionally something like the following in my errorlog:

```
[ERROR] Plugin keyring_file reported: 'File '/usr/local/mysql/mysql-keyring/keyring' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)'
```

In my case (i am running ubuntu) it was **apparmor** that restrict the directory access for mysql (regardless of dir or file permissions) and therefore mysql was not able to read the keyring directory or file.

Maybe CentOS is also using apparmor or has something like that.

Apparmor config file for mysql and Ubuntu already enables access to `/var/lib/mysql-keyring/`. So you should be able to use this dir directly.
My working config:

```
[mysqld]
early-plugin-load=keyring_file.so
keyring_file_data=/var/lib/mysql-keyring/keyring
```

Otherwise you can change or add directories in apparmor in `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld`.

Hope this helps.